# Algorithm in Beamer: all commands are in one line

Tags: beamer, algorithm2e

I need the commands to be in separate lines (If, While, etc). I also tried to get rid of the number of the algorithm as suggested in other posts but the number is still there.
Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout,compress,rgb]{beamer}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amstext, amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} % Figures caption
\usepackage{float} % To place figures where I want with [H]
\usepackage{FiraMono}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[vlined,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]

\captionsetup{labelsep = period} 


\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
\caption*{Finding $z$} 
\begin{algorithmic}
\Require{$x, y$}
\Ensure{$z$}
\State $X \gets x$
\State $N \gets n$
\While{$s <  k$}
  \While{$(t \le k-s)$ and $f$} 
    \State $s \gets 0$
    \If{$ff$ is negative}
       \State $x \gets y-1$
       \State $ff$ \gets false
    \Endif
    \State $t \gets t+1$
  \Endwhile
  \State Assign $y$ to $z$
  \State $jf \gets j+1$
\Endwhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ask a new question! Don't edit your existing question to invalidate the answer you got!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of errors:

- remove `\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}`, this will cause an error.
- the `algorithm2e` package you are loading defined the while loop as `\while{...}{...}` and not `\while{...} \endwhile`
- same error for if
- the `\get` in `\State $ff$ \gets false` must be put into math mode

Some more comments:

- The `T2A` option in `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` seems an odd choice if you at the same time tell babel that your document should be in English ....
- loading the `float` package makes not much sense as beamer does not have a floating mechanism
- don't load the same package multiple times, particularly not with different options
- you don't need to load all these `ams*` package, beamer loads them automatically.
- `indentfirst` also makes not a lot of sense as beamer does not indent paragraphs

One possible approach using the `algorithm2e` syntax:

```
\documentclass[9pt,handout,compress,rgb]{beamer}
%\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{amstext, amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} % Figures caption
%\usepackage{float} % To place figures where I want with [H]
\usepackage{FiraMono}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[vlined,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]

\captionsetup{labelsep = period} 


%\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
%\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
%\newcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
\NoCaptionOfAlgo
\caption{\textbf{Algorithm:} Finding $z$} 
%\begin{algorithmic}
\Input{$x, y$}
\Output{$z$}
 $X \gets x$

$N \gets n$
\While{$s <  k$}{
  \While{$(t \le k-s)$ and $f$}{
     $s \gets 0$
    \If{$ff$ is negative}{
        $x \gets y-1$
       
        $ff \gets$ false
    }
     $t \gets t+1$
  }
   Assign $y$ to $z$
  
   $jf \gets j+1$
}
%\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to remove number 1 after "Algorithm"?

Comment: @Vika `\NoCaptionOfAlgo
\caption{\textbf{Algorithm:} Finding $z$} `

Comment: @Vika If you have a new question, please ask a new question instead of posting random code fragments in comments.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!